# Как построить IPA file с помощью кода, написанного на libgdx?

Tags: android, ios, libgdx, mobile-development

Как создать IPA file с помощью кода, написанного на libgdx?

Comment: а как вы ее на iphone установили?

Comment: я и спрашиваю, как ее на айфон установить

Comment: как создать IPA файл?

Comment: libgdx - это библиотека. библиотеку используют, а код пишут на языке. на каком языке написано приложение?

Comment: java, в андроид студио

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно скачать JDeveloper и ADF с сайта Oracle. А потом переделать ваше приложение для iOS. Как сильно много придётся переделывать зависит от приложения возможно, что будет легче написать с нуля.

Если решите писать с нуля, то вам нужно скачать xCode и изучить Swift или Objective-C.